# Java : Is generic method only with static?

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering do we use generic method only if the method is static ? for non-static you would define a generic class and you don't necessary need it to be generic method. Is that correct ?

for example,

```
  public class Example<E>{

         //this is suffice with no compiler error
         public void doSomething(E [] arr){
                for(E item : arr){
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
         }

         //this wouldn't be wrong, but is it necessary ?
         public <E> doSomething(E [] arr){
                for(E item : arr){
                    System.out.println(item);
                }
         }
  }
```

whereas the compiler will force to add type parameter to make it a generic method if it's static.

```
  public static <E> doSomething(E [] arr){


  }
```

I am not sure if i am correct or not.

Comment: You could also have generic instance methods without the burden of making your class generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Example<E>{
```

defines a generic type for instance's methods and fields.

```
public void <E> doSomething(E [] arr){
```

This defines a second `E` which is different to the first and is likely to be confusing.

Note: `void` is still needed ;)

Static fields and methods do not use the generic types of the class.

```
public static <F> doSomething(F [] arr) { }

private static final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>(); // will not compile.
```

Comment: Static fields and methods do not use the generic types of the class. Why is that ?

Comment: Every instance of a class can have a different generic type.  This has no meaning for static members.

Comment: What about non-static fields and methods ? Do they share the generic type of the class ? I mean do they have to ?

Comment: They don't have to use the generic but it is always available to be used.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you declare an `Example<String> example = new Example<String>();`.

- `public void doSomething(E [] arr)` will expect a `String[]` argument
- `public <E> void doSomething(E [] arr)` will expect an array of any type (it's not the same `E` as in `Example<E>`)
- `public static <E> void doSomething(E [] arr)` will expect an array of any type

In any case, since your `Example<E>` can be parameterized, you can't use that `E` in a static call as it will be instance dependent. It would be a bit like calling a non static member from a static method. So you have to redefine it locally.

Comment: You could for example create an `Example<String>` then an `Example<Integer>`. Static methods are not related to a specific instance but to the class. So there is no way a static method could resolve `E` since there could be several of them.

Comment: My analogy was that if you have a `private String abc;` (an instance field), you can't access it from a static method, because there is one `abc` string per instance of the class.

Comment: So in that case I have to use anything else other than E ? Will it give a compiler error if I use E ? and what do you mean redefine it locally

Comment: when you write `public static <E> void method(E arg)` inside a generic class like `Example<E>`, the E in the method declaration and the E in the class declaration are not the same. It is as if you had written `public static <T> void method(T arg)` (which you probably should do to make it clear). That's what I mean by redefining locally: your method is generic, but uses its own generic type, which is unrelated to the generic type of the containing class.

Comment: Get it. I am wondering do we use generic instance method inside a generic class whenever we don't want to use the type from the generic class. I mean even if we put the same type lets say E, in the generic instance method the E will be a different E. is that correct ?

Comment: @user1389813 Yes, `public void method(E e)` using the same `E` as in `Example<E>` but `public <E> void method(E e)` uses its own `E`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the the `java.util.Collection` interface. It is declared as:

```
public interface Collection<E>{
  //...
  <T> T[] toArray(T[] a);
}
```

The `toArray` is a generic instance method using a type parameter `T`, which has no relation whatsoever with the type parameter `E` from the interface declaration.

This a good example from the JDK itself that illustrates the value of having generic instance methods.